# Framework ("wrapped" static lib) with two executables

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

Is there a way to create a framework with two executables inside, one for device and one for simulator, instead of making one fat lib?

Comment: Is there anything diff than fat lib/ framework contain fat lib? This might work with run script that rename the file while building, but what's the point?

Comment: When I supply my framework to developers, they get it with fat lib inside. I assume, that when they upload their applications to App Store, they can cut the simulator arc part from the lib to reduce the lib size. I assume, that if it were possible to supply a framework with two different libs, one for device and one for sim, they will not need to cut it by themselves, because at compile time, the desired lib will be included in the binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option. We can see this on libxml example of Apple framework, they have one for device and one for simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You should pack your project as fat framework (different from fat library), this way will make sure the app must strip out the simulator part in order to upload to app store, and the stripping script can be easily obtained in some famous framework like Realm's dynamic framework (required iOS 8+ - if your lib is iOS 7, you can try rewrite the script)

Comment: "fat framework" is the same fat lib, but wrapped inside framework. And, I asking whether there is a way... just read one more time my question